# Why does UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary not let the user pick an album?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am currently developing an iPad application for iPad, where I use a UIPopOverController in combination with UIImagePickerController to let the user select an image from their iPad (with sourceType UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum). This works great and as expected, but it only allows the client to browse the SavedPhotos album obviously. If I change the picker to use UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary, the window will still display its albums, but it'll be static (meaning I can scroll, but I can't select albums, and when I scroll down or up, the view will only pop back if I tap the screen again).

Does the PhotoLibrary require extra settings to work properly? I tried numerous approaches but I'm all out of luck here.

The setup is an OpenGL view, on which I spawn the UIPopOverController with the UIImagePicker. For the sake of clarity, here's the code:

```
-(void)showPicker
{
    if(![pController isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [pController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(50,100,200,300) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
    }
    else
    { 
        pController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    pController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];

    // Code works properly if I only set it to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    else if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) picker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    else { NSLog(@"Error: Could not pick appropriate sourceType"); }

    picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage, nil];
    picker.delegate = self;
    pController.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing=NO;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there are images in the photo library? From the docs `... For example, if you attempt to pick an image from the user’s library and the library is empty, this method returns NO. Similarly, if the camera is already in use, this method returns NO.`

Comment: Yeah, there are plenty of them.. The albums display fine (it shows there are images in them), but I can't select any of the albums because it won't let me for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with *iOS6* ?
I know that in *Settings/Privacy* you have to allow your app to see in the *Photos Albums*.